# Error al compilar código en c++ con Visual Code

Tags: c++, string, compilar

Estoy realizando un código en c++ bajo el SO de Ubuntu y empleando Visual Code.
Al compilar el código me salta el siguiente error al emplear la función stod para convertir un dato de un fichero de string a double:

> ‘stod’ was not declared in this scope

El cual se refiere a la siguiente porción del código

```
for (int i = 0; i < 164; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 164; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 164; k++) {
            file >> data;
            double auxData = stod(data);
            cube[i][j][k] = auxData;
        }
    }
}
```

Al inicio del código he incluido el header de la clase string y uso el namespace para no tener que emplear std:: constantemente.

Comment: Puede que sea pertinente que agregues que compilador estas usando, y que versión es.

Answer (score 2):

Según la documentación de [`std::sto???`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) éstas funciones están disponibles en la cabecera `<string>` desde C++11.

Si estás usando un compilador incompatible con C++11 o estás usando un compilador antiguo o estás usando un compilador compatible con C++11 pero no le pasas los parámetros de compilación adecuados, podrías tener el error que describes.

Verifica la versión de compilador que estás usando y/o intenta añadir `-std=c++1x` a los parámetros de compilación.

Comment: Sabes donde puedo encontrar información para saber cómo comprobar lo del compilador?

Comment: @DiegoMartinez es difícil de saber si ni siquiera se que compilador estás usando. En algún lugar de tu sistema tendrás el compilador al cuál puedes interrogar sobre su versión. Por ejemplo, si estás usando `gcc` puedes escribir en la línea de comandos `gcc --version`.